# When I export my Java program, why does the frame come up but not the panel?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, jpanel

I wanted to export my game into a .jar file. It exported; when I ran it the frame came up, but the panel didn't load. I have my frame and panel in two different class files but I didn't think that made a difference. Also, It completely works in Eclipse. I exported my .jar file under Runnable Jar File and packaged required libraries into generated jar. In the SlashRunnerPanel I imported and resized many images. Can that be the problem?

Here is my code for the frame:

```
package baseFiles;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SlashRunnerFrame {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // Create new JFrame (the window)

    frame.setSize(1000, 800); // Set it to 1000x800 pixels
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Quit on red X

    frame.setResizable(false); // Disallow resizing of window

    // Change this line if you want to use a different panel
    SlashRunnerPanel panel = new SlashRunnerPanel();
    frame.add(panel); // Staple the panel to the JFrame
    frame.setVisible(true); // So we can see our window
    panel.mainLoop();
  }
}
```

Here is my code for the panel:

```
package baseFiles;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.File;
import player.Player;
import surroundings.Obstacle;

public class SlashRunnerPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener,
ActionListener, MouseListener
{
public static boolean mailbox1 = false;
 Color skin = new Color(255, 223, 196);
boolean goo = true;

BufferedImage origMailBox;
BufferedImage house;
BufferedImage ReplaceableBackgroundPic;
BufferedImage origPlayerBack;
BufferedImage origPlayerFront;
BufferedImage origletter;
BufferedImage blackScreen;
BufferedImage exclamation;
BufferedImage borderRocks;
BufferedImage pause;
Image ReplaceableBackground;
Image resizedHouse;
Image mailbox;
Image PlayerBack;
Image PlayerFront;
Image letter;
Image Exclamation;

ArrayList<Obstacle> obstacles = new ArrayList<Obstacle>();
Obstacle mailboxRegion;
Player player;
Obstacle Beginning;
String ps = System.getProperty("file.separator");

//Animation for walking
boolean aniUp = true;
boolean aniDown;
boolean aniRight;
boolean aniLeft; 
boolean lastAni;

//mail
boolean openMail = false;
boolean isMailbox;
boolean mailcontinue;
boolean arrow = true;
boolean showMailRegion;

//Scene
boolean begin = true;
int cmX;
int cmY;
boolean obstaclesInBeginning = true;
boolean showObstInBegin;

//Keys
boolean showObstacles;
boolean stats;
boolean pausebool;

boolean play = true;

public SlashRunnerPanel()
{   
    try{
    borderRocks = ImageIO.read(new File("src" + ps + "Images" + ps + "Boundary.png"));
    } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
            try{
            exclamation = ImageIO.read(new File("src" + ps + "Images" + ps + "Exclamation.png"));
            } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
            try{
            origletter = ImageIO.read(new File("src" + ps + "Images" + ps + "Scroll.png"));
            } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
            try{
                blackScreen = ImageIO.read(new File("src" + ps + "Images" + ps + "BlackScreen.png"));
            } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            try{
                house = ImageIO.read(new File("src" + ps + "Images" + ps + "House.png"));
            } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            try{
                ReplaceableBackgroundPic = ImageIO.read(new File("src" + ps + "Images" + ps + "ReplaceableBackground.png"));
            } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            try{
                origMailBox = ImageIO.read(new File("src" + ps + "Images" + ps + "SmallMailbox.png"));
            } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            try{
                origPlayerBack = ImageIO.read(new File("src" + ps + "Images" + ps + "WarriorBack.png"));
            } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            try{
                origPlayerFront = ImageIO.read(new File("src" + ps + "Images" + ps + "WarriorFront.png"));
            } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            try{
                pause = ImageIO.read(new File("src" + ps + "Images" + ps + "Pause.png"));
            } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

public void mainLoop()
{

    obstacles.add(new Obstacle(140, 170, 300, 545));
    obstacles.add(new Obstacle(560, 170, 350, 500));
    obstacles.add(new Obstacle(500, 900, 800, 100));

    this.setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    addMouseListener(this);
       Exclamation = exclamation.getScaledInstance(20, 20, Image.SCALE_FAST);
       letter = origletter.getScaledInstance(500, 500, Image.SCALE_FAST);
       ReplaceableBackground = ReplaceableBackgroundPic.getScaledInstance(1600, 2336, Image.SCALE_FAST);
       resizedHouse = house.getScaledInstance((int) (getWidth() / 5), (int) (getHeight() / 4), Image.SCALE_FAST);
       mailbox = origMailBox.getScaledInstance((int)(getWidth() / 6), (int) (getHeight() / 6), Image.SCALE_FAST);
       Image PlayerBack = origPlayerBack.getScaledInstance((int)(getWidth() / 30), (int) (getHeight() / 12), Image.SCALE_FAST);
       Image PlayerFront = origPlayerFront.getScaledInstance((int)(getWidth() / 30), (int) (getHeight() / 12), Image.SCALE_FAST);

       player = new Player(585, 725, (int)(getWidth() / 30), (int) (getHeight() / 12), false, PlayerFront, PlayerBack);
       mailboxRegion = new Obstacle(795, 750, 50, 50);
       Beginning = new Obstacle(450, 750, 100, 100);

   while(goo)
   {
        if(player.intersects(Beginning) && obstaclesInBeginning)
            player.playerX += 10;
        if(!player.dead)
       player.move(obstacles); 
       updateCamera();
       if(player.experience == 100)
       {
           player.experience = 0;
           player.experienceLv++;
       }
       checkCondition();
       repaint();
       wait(100);
   }

}

public void wait(int milsec)
{
    try{
        Thread.sleep(milsec);
    } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);


    if(begin && !pausebool && play) //For beginning
    {
        g.drawImage(ReplaceableBackground, 150 - cmX, -620 - cmY, null);
        g.drawImage(resizedHouse, 600 - cmX, 563 - cmY, null);
        g.drawImage(mailbox, 720 - cmX, 670 - cmY, null);
        g.drawImage(pause,  900, 10, null);
        if(obstaclesInBeginning)
            g.drawImage(borderRocks,523 - cmX,755 - cmY,null);
    }

    if(pausebool)
    {
        g.drawRect(0,  0,  1000,  1000);
    }

    if(arrow                                                                  )
    {
        g.drawImage(Exclamation, 790 - cmX, 665 - cmY, null);
    }
    player.drawTo(g, 500, 450);


    if(isMailbox)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.magenta);
        g.setFont(new Font("AlgerianBasD", Font.BOLD, 15));
        g.drawString("Press 'Q' to open the mailbox!", 600, 300);
    }

    if(showObstInBegin)
    {
        obstBegin(g);
    }

    if(play)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(738, 35, 250, 30);
        g.fillRect(738, 90, 250, 30);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(738, 35, (int)(player.playerHealth * 2.5), 30);
        g.setFont(new Font("AlgerianBasD", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g.drawString("Health:", 738, 30);
        g.setColor(new Color(128, 255, 210));
        g.drawString("Experience:", 738, 85);
        g.fillRect(738, 90, (int)(player.experience * 2.5), 30);
        g.setColor(new Color(10, 133, 255));
        g.drawString("" + player.experienceLv, 850, 110);
    }

    if(showObstacles)
    {
            drawObst(g, obstacles);
    }

    if(showMailRegion)
    {
        drawMailRegion(g);
    }

    if(stats)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.drawRect(1, 600, 200, 300);
        g.setFont(new Font("AlgerianBasD", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("Stats:", 50,  620);
        g.setColor(new Color(140, 0, 0));
        g.drawString("Overall Strength: " + player.completeStrength, 3, 650);
        g.setColor(new Color(100, 88, 115));
        g.drawString("Armor: " + player.playerArmor, 3, 680);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.drawString("X: " + player.playerX, 3, 710);
        g.drawString("Y: " + player.playerY, 3, 740);
    }

    if(openMail && !mailcontinue)
    {
        g.drawImage(blackScreen,0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(letter, 250, 200, null);
    }


}

public void checkCondition()
{
       if(player.intersects(mailboxRegion))
       {
           isMailbox = true;

       } if( isMailbox && !player.intersects(mailboxRegion))
       {
           isMailbox = false;
       }
}

public void drawObst(Graphics g, ArrayList<Obstacle> obst)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < obst.size(); i++)
    {
    g.setColor(Color.magenta);
    g.fillRect(obst.get(i).getX() - cmX, obst.get(i).getY() - cmY, obst.get(i).getWidth(), obst.get(i).getHeight());
    }

}

public void drawMailRegion(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.fillRect(mailboxRegion.getX() - cmX, mailboxRegion.getY() - cmY, mailboxRegion.getWidth(), mailboxRegion.getHeight());
}

public void obstBegin(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    g.fillRect(Beginning.getX() - cmX, Beginning.getY() - cmY, Beginning.getWidth(), Beginning.getHeight());
}
public void updateCamera()
{
    cmX = player.playerX - getWidth() / 2;
    cmY = player.playerY - getHeight() / 2;
}

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
  {
      int key = e.getKeyCode();
      if(key == KeyEvent.VK_L)
      {
          if(stats == true)
          {
              stats = false;
          } else
          stats = true;
      }

      if(isMailbox && !openMail && key == KeyEvent.VK_Q)
      {

          openMail = true;
          isMailbox = false;
          arrow = false;
          obstaclesInBeginning = false;

      }

      else if(openMail && key == KeyEvent.VK_Q)
      {
          obstaclesInBeginning = false;
          openMail = false;
          repaint();
      }

      if(key == KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS)
      {
          if(pausebool)
              pausebool = false;
          else
              pausebool = true;
      }

      if(key == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH)
      {
          if(showObstacles == true)
          {
              showMailRegion = false;
              showObstacles = false;
              showObstInBegin = false;
          } else {
          showObstacles = true;
          showMailRegion = true;
          showObstInBegin = true;
          }
      }

      if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
      {
          player.up = true;
          player.aniUp = true;
          player.aniDown = false;
          player.aniRight = false;
          player.aniLeft = false;

      }
      if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
      {
          player.down = true;
          player.aniDown = true;
          player.aniUp = false;
          player.aniRight = false;
          player.aniLeft = false;

      }
      if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
      {
          player.left = true;
      }
      if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
      {
          player.right = true;
      }
      repaint();
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
  {
      int key = e.getKeyCode();
      if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
      {
          player.up = false;
      }
      if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
      {
          player.down = false;
      }
      if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
      {
          player.left = false;
      }
      if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
      {
          player.right = false;
      }
  }

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
  {

  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
  {

  }

  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
  {

  }

  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
  {

  }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
  {

  }

  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
  {

  }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. When it was loading in the images in the .jar file it was trying to access the folder on my desktop instead of the one in the jar file. So it sent an error because it was trying to access a file that is out of the .jar file. My solution was to replace:

```
try{
yourImageVariableName = ImageIO.read(new File("yourImagePath1" + ps + "yourImagePath2" + ps + "yourImage.png"));
} catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

with:

```
try{
yourImageVariableName = ImageIO.read(yourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/yourImagePath2/yourImage.png"));
} catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the game on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Swing is not thread safe; if you try to create and modify controls off of the Event Dispatch Thread than things may not work as you expect; controls not displaying is a very common result.

[`EventQueue.invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) is the most common way to make tasks run on the EDT, as seen here:
    package baseFiles;

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SlashRunnerFrame
{
  public static void main(String args [])
  {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // Create new JFrame (the window)

        frame.setSize(1000, 800); // Set it to 1000x800 pixels
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Quit on red X

        frame.setResizable(false); // Disallow resizing of window

        // Change this line if you want to use a different panel
        SlashRunnerPanel panel = new SlashRunnerPanel(); 
        frame.add(panel); // Staple the panel to the JFrame
        frame.setVisible(true); // So we can see our window
        panel.mainLoop();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If this doesn't fix your problem, then your issue is almost certainly in the code of `SlashRunnerPanel`, not this code.

Comment: Nether of the worked. Please keep in mind it my code works in eclipse. Thanks for all of the support!

Comment: @Jack can you edit your question to include information about how you build your jar and the code of `SlashRunnerPanel`?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(someHeight, someWidth)) and after that frame.pack()

EDIT:

Try this:
    package baseFiles;

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class SlashRunnerFrame {

  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  SlashRunnerPanel panel = new SlashRunnerPanel();

  public SlashRunnerFrame(){
     // Create new JFrame (the window)
    panel.mainLoop();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 800));

    frame.setSize(1000, 800); // Set it to 1000x800 pixels
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Quit on red X
    frame.setResizable(false); // Disallow resizing of window

    // Change this line if you want to use a different panel

    frame.add(panel); // Staple the panel to the JFrame
    frame.setVisible(true); // So we can see our window

    frame.pack();
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new SlashRunnerFrame();
  }
}
```

see if it works

modify your panel before adding it to the frame.

Comment: Nether of the worked. Please keep in mind it my code works in eclipse. Thanks for all of the support!

Comment: @Jack your SlashRunnerPanel  is extending JPanel?

Comment: Yes it extends JPanel and implements KeyListener, MouseListener, and ActionListener.

Comment: Could the issue be that my computer claims that my Java version is outdated when I updated it 4 times?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero
 at java.awt.image.ReplicateScaleFilter.<init>(ReplicateScaleFilter.java:102)
 at java.awt.Image.getScaledInstance(Image.java:174)
 at baseFiles.SlashRunnerPanel.mainLoop(SlashRunnerPanel.java:125)
 at baseFiles.SlashRunnerFrame.<init>(SlashRunnerFrame.java:13)
 at baseFiles.SlashRunnerFrame.main(SlashRunnerFrame.java:28)

Comment: Well, dunno. Post your SlashRunnerPanel code, maybe the problem is in there.

Comment: @Jack definitely a problem with your SlashRunnerPanel.

Comment: Could it be the loading of the images?

Comment: By the exception, probably, see whats wrong in line 102 of your RunnerPanel. 

I think the main question changed, and you have to do a little debugging before post more information.

Comment: I dont understand though because it works in eclipse with my original code.

Comment: After you export your JAR, open it with winrar and import all your image files in. It should work. Keep the same folders you use outside the jars.

Comment: I don't know how to use winrar and have tried to use it for the past 15 minutes. I use a Mac. Is there any other way?

Comment: Sorry about all of the trouble.

Comment: I don'k know Jack, im not a mac user. Google for how to open a java jar file in Mac, should be a way.